# Ember: redirecting to the requested url after login

Tags: php, laravel, ember.js

I am using ember and laravel for my web application. In this i send some hyperlinks to others having the reports. when the user opens the link, the ember sends a request to the server to check if the user is a valid user(ie, if he is logged in). If he has logged in, the application opens the link. Else it will request to login. My problem is once the user logs in, it gets redirected to the main page. But i need to redirect him to the link which i have sent it to him. I am not using laravel or ember for authentication. I store the user details in a cookie and use it to validate the user. can anyone suggest a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the url before redirect to login page.
You can store the url in cookie.